# Best practice for deploying spring boot application on Amazon

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, spring-security, spring-boot, facebook-messenger

I've devloped a chat bot application using the Facebook [Messenger platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform).
I used [Spring Boot](http://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) with embedded Tomcat for the web platform.
The application should run on Amazon aws, open to the WWW, and to be used as a webhook for recieving callbacks from Messenger over https.

I need an advice how to secure the application, so it won't be hacked or flooded with requests that are not coming from Facebook.

I thought to make the application require secured (ssl) connection, but using the "security.require_ssl=true" in application.properties didn't do the work. Perhaps I don't know what is the meaning of this and how to configure it propertly.
Is there a best practice how to block requests which are not https requests? Or a way to block requests which are coming outside Messenger in the application level?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

In the meantime, I blocked requests from other IPs in application layer using the handler interceptor:

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer, WebMvcConfigurer{


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                    throws Exception {
                if (! (request.getRemoteAddr().equals("173.252.88.66") || request.getRemoteAddr().equals("127.0.0.1")|| request.getRemoteAddr().equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"))){
                    logger.warn("Request is not coming from authorized remote address: " + request.getRemoteAddr()+". Rejecting");
                    response.getWriter().write("Unauthorized Address");
                    response.setStatus(401);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

}
```

Comment: From facebook reference documentation, I see there is a possibility to set a callback token (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference), have you configured one? do you receive it on spring application side (as a path or get parameter) ?

Comment: @GuyBouallet The token is for a first-time verification. The ongoing callbacks do not contain any token. Did you see something that I missed?

Comment: Have you checked if there is a http header called X-Hub-Signature In the requests received by tomcat?

Comment: @GuyBouallet Thank you! I really did missed this point. Now I just have to find out out to compare the payload with the signature. Do you know how to create a "unicode escaped hex lowercase string" from a simple json? I beleive I can use the interceptor too, right?

Comment: I added an answer so that you can accept it. Please see sample implementa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the X-Hub-signature HTTP header available in the requests sent by Facebook to your webhook URL.

In your case, you may define a filter or interceptor for the verification of the signature. You can also do it in your controller as in the this example I found in [RealTimeUpdateController.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook/blob/master/spring-social-facebook-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/facebook/web/RealTimeUpdateController.java) from the spring social project.

```
private boolean verifySignature(String payload, String signature) throws Exception {

        if (!signature.startsWith("sha1=")) {

            return false;

        }

        String expected = signature.substring(5);       

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);

        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(applicationSecret.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);

        mac.init(signingKey);

        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(payload.getBytes());

        String actual = new String(Hex.encode(rawHmac));

        return expected.equals(actual);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

a lot to say so I am sure I will miss some points.

- setting SSL is a first good thing but make sure you get a certificate. [lets encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is a good thing if you dont want to pay for SSL certificate.

  Just [seeing](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/aws-announces-certificate-manager-similar-to-le/9289) aws provides an alternative to letsencrypt
- [Security Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) You can see Security Group as something similar to a firewall so you can control which port is opened, external and internal flows.
- Look at [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) which control who and how can get access to your AWS account
- obvious : change your password. do not let default password for installation you could make on the instance

read some of https://aws.amazon.com/security/security-resources/ to get more information about what you can do

> it won't be hacked or flooded with requests

sorry to say but most probably it will be - It does not need to be an advanced hacker to run scanner and scan IPs and check open ports / brute force login etc ...

Comment: Your answer gives interesting advices but it is focused on securing the AWS server side in general. The question involves a specific client which is facebook; So securing the communication requires to check what facebook support (SSL + payload signature).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Guy Bouallet help I added the signature check.
I added it in my controller and not in the interceptor, to avoid the problem of [How to read data twice in spring](http://www.myjavarecipes.com/how-to-read-post-request-data-twice-in-spring/) which seems a little complicated.

So here is it:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public void doHandleCallback(@RequestBody String body, @RequestHeader(value = "X-Hub-Signature") String signature) throws IOException {
    if (!verifyRequestSignature(body.getBytes(), signature)){
        logger.error ("Signature mismatch.");
        throw new MismatchSignatureException(signature);
    }
    MessengerCallback callback = mapper.readValue(body, MessengerCallback.class);
    logger.info("Incoming Callback: " + body );
    for (EventData entry : callback.getEntry()) {
        for (ReceivedMessagingObject message : entry.getMessaging()) {
            if (message.isMessage() || message.isPostback()) {
                doHandleMessage(message);
            }
            else if (message.isDelivery()){
                doHandleDelivery(message);
            }
        }
    }       
}

private boolean verifyRequestSignature(byte[] payload, String signature) {
    if (!signature.startsWith("sha1="))
        return false;
    String expected = signature.substring(5);
    System.out.println("Expected signature: " + expected); //for debugging purposes

    String hashResult = HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex(APP_SECRET.getBytes(), payload);
    System.out.println("Calculated signature: " + hashResult);
    if (hashResult.equals(expected)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And this is the Exception handling class:

```
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="Request Signature mismatch")
    public class MismatchSignatureException extends RuntimeException {
    private String signature;

    public MismatchSignatureException(String signature) {
        this.signature = signature;
    }
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Signature mismatch: " + signature;
    }
```